# Drupal7 provoking ajax error in Views (installed in sub folder)

Tags: views, ajax

I have installed drupal 7 in a subdirectory of my domain. The subdirectory is masked as explained on the following site: http://kahthong.com/2011/05/how-serve-drupal-sub-directory-web-root-0

Now, this works pretty well EXCEPT when an AJAX query is done by the drupal backend. This will always produce an error. One example is in the Views-UI module: when I try to edit some setting in a view, an error like the follow will pop up:

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: ***mydomain****/en/admin/structure/views/ajax/display/store/page/row_options
StatusText: error
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 0
```

My guess is that the URL rewriting specified in the .htaccess is not being applied. Therefore my two questions:

- ***Why does the URL rewrite not work for AJAX queries***
- ***How can I fix this?***

Answer (score 1):

I have found that my problem is distinct: the AJAX request has included the www in front of my domain meanwhile I have set the default without www.

So I had to change in settings.php the base_url FROM 'http://www.mydomain.com' TO 'http://mydomain.com'

Cheers